# How to customize tables in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm working on a sales team site for my organization. In this site, I have added a page called 'Target' where I added a table using Text web part which looks like this:

[image: Table using Text webpart]

But this page looks very static. Thus said, to add data in this table as a user, they have to use the edit page option. Also, I'm not sure if this table can distinguish between rows and columns such that the table data has to be transmitted to some other web part or dashboard.

Are there any better web part than text? I tried list but list does not look like the one below.

Any suggestion how I could improve this and what are the options I have?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option to get close to what you have now would be to actually build an Excel spreadsheet and then embed it on your page. Your other option would be to build an PowerApp but that might take some time to learn. You can't get what you're looking for using a list.

[How to Embed Excel Spreadsheet to Modern SharePoint Online Pages?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2020/05/sharepoint-online-embed-excel-spreadsheet-in-modern-pages.html)

[Embed your Excel workbook on your web page or blog from SharePoint or OneDrive for Business](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773)

Comment: If we use powerapps to customize the list, can we show the UI in sharePoint as it is in powerapp? Or will it redirect to powerapp when a user try to open the list?

Comment: You can embed the PowerApp on a SharePoint page to interact with it.